# Readiness probe failed error in weave kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, weave

I have cluster where I have 10 worker nodes on `Raspberry pi` and master is running on `Ubuntu 16.04`. Everything seems to be working fine but sometime a pod running on node shows below error:

`Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m (x3 over 18m)   kubelet, w188  (combined from similar events): Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "6fa511fb1d292702aa99318b785f5011307601868ff2520c542515a239924c16" network for pod "deployment-6w24f": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "deployment-6w24f_aps-namespace" network: unable to allocate IP address: Post http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/6fa511fb1d292702aa99318b785f5011307601868ff2520c542515a239924c16: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused`

I am using weave for networking and it shows below error on kube dashboard:

`Readiness probe failed: Get http://127.0.0.1:6784/status: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused
Back-off restarting failed container
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "weave-net-token-txqhk" : couldn't propagate object cache: timed out waiting for the condition`

The node shows this error and after sometime it starts working fine automatically. This is happening every now and then with multiple nodes. I used below commands to init the cluster and weave:

```
sudo kubeadm init --token-ttl=0 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.8.12

kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

Can anyone please guide me on how to resolve this.

Comment: Have you try to pass bridged IPv4 traffic to iptables by running ```sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1```?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What worked for me was to add `iptable` rules with the IP range of my `kube-dns` service.

```
# kubectl get svc -n kube-system 
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   16m
[root@master kubernetes]#
```

Since IP of kube-dns is `10.96.0.10` then, the valid range for iptable rule would be `10.96.0.1/32`

```
# iptables -t nat -I KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.1/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
```

More about this issue can be found [here](http://www.bennythejudge.com/kubernetes/cni/weaver/2020/05/02/weave-pod-crashes-on-worker-digitalocean.html).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had missed deleting `/etc/cni/net.d/10-aws.conflist` file on each of the nodes.

In summary, we need to follow below steps:

1. kubectl delete ds aws-node -n kube-system
2. delete `/etc/cni/net.d/10-aws.conflist` on each of the node
3. restart kube-proxy pods
4. Install Weave Net resources.
   E.g.: kubectl apply -f https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/releases/download/v2.8.1/weave-daemonset-k8s.yaml

Official Documentation to install [Weave Net on AWS EKS Cluster](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/#-installing-on-eks)